# How to consolidate lots of Powershell Scripts into one

Tags: powershell

I have this script

```
Add-Type -Name Window -Namespace Console -MemberDefinition '
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);
'
function Hide-Console
{
$consolePtr = [Console.Window]::GetConsoleWindow()
#0 hide
[Console.Window]::ShowWindow($consolePtr, 0)
}
Hide-Console

$docs = [environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")
$zwift = "$docs\Zwift"                  # Zwift data directory
$log = "$zwift\Logs\Log.txt"            # Path to Zwift log file
$output = "$zwift\Logs\GroupEvents.txt"  # File to write output to
$delay = 6000                           # Delay in ms between updates of the file

Function Write-SlowOutput {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
            HelpMessage="How long to pause for (ms)")]
[int32]$waitFor,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
            HelpMessage="File to output to")]
[string]$outputFile,
[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
[Object]$input
)
BEGIN {}
PROCESS {
    Write-Host $input
    if ($outputFile) {
        Out-File -Encoding UTF8 -FilePath $outputFile -InputObject $input
    }
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $waitFor
}
END {}

}

Get-Content -Tail 0 -Wait -Encoding "UTF8" $log | 
  Select-String "GroupEvents: Linedup for group (.*), subgroup" |
   % {$_.matches.groups[1].value} |
    Write-SlowOutput -outputFile $output -waitFor $delay
```

This script looks at the log file of my game and extracts some text based on the select-string line

```
Select-String "GroupEvents: Linedup for group (.*), subgroup" |
```

Expected output is a simple text phrase or sentence like Group Run. But it's really not important exactly what the text output is.

I have multiple instances of this script running each looking for a different line in the Log file and outputting a different line of text. All to the same output file. Basically the latest line found overwrites the previous one, which is what I require.

So, how can I rewrite this script so I don't need to run multiple instances, please? For example..

```
Select-String "GroupEvents: Linedup for group (.*), subgroup" |
Select-String "Workout(.*)" |
Select-String "GroupEvents: Started in group (.*), subgroup" |
Select-String "Run Device Selected: (.*)" |
```

I would like the script to search each of these strings and simply output the latest one found in the Log file to the output file.

I have tried just copying the last three lines of code, but this didn't work. I'm not a coder (clearly!) so just best guessing and using trial and error mostly.

Any help with this greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated Answer: I'm solving the problem you are actually asking now, which is "how do I call `Select-String` with different patterns on the same input?"

Each time new log entries are found, it will pass all the new entries into the `For-Each` loop.  We can then pass the current object (`$_`) as a pipeline object into the function `ProcessLog`.  `ProcessLog` will test the input with `Select-String` for each pattern and pass the item to your `Write-SlowOutput` function.

```
$log = "test.log"
$output = "output.log"

$patterns = @("GroupEvents: Linedup for group (.*), subgroup", 
              "Workout(.*)", 
              "GroupEvents: Started in group (.*), subgroup", 
              "Run Device Selected: (.*)")

function ProcessLog {
    [CmdletBinding()] Param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$item)

    Write-Output "Running with $item"

    foreach($pattern in $patterns)
    {
        $save = (Select-String -InputObject $item -Pattern $pattern | % { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value })

        if(-not [string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($save))
        {
            $save.Trim('(').Trim(')') | Set-Content $output
            return
        }
    }
}

Get-Content -Tail 0 -Wait -Encoding "UTF8" $log | % { $_ | ProcessLog }
```

I tested this successfully using `Set-Content` to write to the output file, so I just have to assume it will work properly with your `Write-SlowOutput` function.

Comment: thank you. Does this then write that last line to the output file?

Comment: I updated the answer to include appending to a file.

Comment: Thanks once again. Help an idiot out here! I understand what your code is doing, but how does it integrate with the code already in the script? What do I erase and what do I keep? Apologies for being a bit dumb.

Comment: You can basically replace your last line with all this code.  You don't need to do Get-Content because Select-String can read directly from the file.  I'm not familiar with `Write-SlowOutput` (and a quick Google doesn't turn up any documentation), so `Add-Content` will write to the file.  Replace `filename.txt` with `$output`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately I can't get it to work. I'm sure it's something I've done wrong! I'll keep trying. Thank again Phil.

Comment: I realized that I messed up and had `.LineNumber` instead of `.Maximum`.  I ran the script against actual input and updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: This is almost exactly as I need Phil thanks. The only thing my original script did was to constantly monitor the log file and update instantly when it detected a change. It would then overwrite the entry in the output file so there is only ever one entry. I bet you're glad you started this!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212727/discussion-between-philselmer-and-stephen-cousins).

Comment: If this sufficiently answered your question, please mark it as the answer.